# popover inside nested tables falls behinde the outer table

Tags: html, css, nested-table

i have a table that needed to have scrollable tbody, so i did this:
[image]

And i have a popover(Bootstarp3 css no js) inside the second column, and i just turn the display on and off. but it falls behind the outer table. see the pic below :
[image]

The table's header is from the outer table and the content is in the inner one.

I tried setting the z-index on the popover and its container and all their parents but with no success.

Any suggestions?

UPDATE:

I am not using bootstraps javascript just css.

The `outer-div` has `overflow:auto` witch needs it for making the content scrollable so i can't set it to `visible`.

Do i have to move the `popover` html out of `outer-div` is that the only way?

The columns that have the popover are custom angular directives.

Comment: does your table have `overflow:hidden` on it?

Comment: @DarrenSweeney good catch not the table but the `outer-div` has and it needs it for the scroll and can't turn it off

Answer (score 0):

Try setting popover's container to `body`. For example:

```
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
    container: "body"    
});
```

Or put `data-container="body"` attribute on the element.
Based on [Bootstrap popover options](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers-options)

Comment: I am not using the bootstarps js components just css, the html is prerendered inside the td. if i have to i should write the js my self to position them correctly and move the popovers html outside of the `outer-div`

Comment: Any reason why you cannot use bootstrap js? Can you at least create a jsfiddle, so we can see the code?